# How to remove quotation marks after web scraping with vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I start a web scraping of webpage and I notice the following when I copy the cells.

```
"
In stock
"
"
4 to 10 bus days
"
"
4 to 10 bus days
"
"
4 to 10 bus days
"
```

I tried to remove them together with the extra CR LF in order to have the following

```
In stock
4 to 10 bus days
4 to 10 bus days
4 to 10 bus days
```

I tried the following which are not working

```
Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".product-section")
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(Replace(Trim(availability.innerText), Chr(34), ""), ":")
wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = (arr(UBound(arr)))

Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".product-section")
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(Replace(Trim(availability.innerText), """", ""), ":")
wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = (arr(UBound(arr)))

Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".product-section")
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(Trim(availability.innerText), ":")
wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = (arr(UBound(arr)))
```

It has to do with webpage? other webpages have normal output?

How can I fix it?

The first URL is
https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=11684
and
https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1485
which says In Stock

Comment: It is e.g the https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1591

Comment: The results I expect are something like In stock
4 to 10 bus days
4 to 10 bus days
4 to 10 bus days

Comment: I just translated them :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185388/discussion-between-maria-georgali-and-qharr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is better to use a direct selector but as some links, where out of stock, second class changes to `.prod-stock-out`, you need a test to determine which descendant class selector to use.

CSS:

```
.product-section .prod-stock
```

VBA:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".product-section .prod-stock").innerText
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, wks As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, urls()
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    urls = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("A1:A2").Value) 'adjust for range containing all urls
    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For j = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .Navigate2 urls(j)

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            wks.Cells(j, "C") = .document.querySelector(".col-sm-8 h1").innerText

            If .document.getElementsByClassName("product-section")(0).getElementsByClassName("prod-stock").Length = 0 Then
                wks.Cells(j, "D") = .document.querySelector(".product-section .prod-stock-out").innerText
            Else
                wks.Cells(j, "D") = .document.querySelector(".product-section .prod-stock").innerText
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

You could also use the more readable:

```
If .document.querySelectorAll(".product-section .prod-stock").Length = 0 Then
    wks.Cells(j, "D") = .document.querySelector(".product-section .prod-stock-out").innerText
Else
    wks.Cells(j, "D") = .document.querySelector(".product-section .prod-stock").innerText
End If
```

Comment: I do the Dim arr() As String
        arr = Split(Replace(availability.innerText, Chr$(34), vbNullString), ":") but nothing the same

Comment: I want only the last one word

Comment: Only one item of a list is without quotation marks the other they keep 2 CR and LF with quotation marks

Comment: Each row produces an array with the above. So I need the last word of each array to have no quotation marks when I take it out from array

Comment: From the quotation marks cr and lf is perfect BUT by running it the results are totally wrong why?

Comment: I did wks.Cells(i, "D") to display them on D column I did it wrong?.

Comment: I did it is working!! but you thought it a bit wrong. I want the info from the main product not the below products which are random.. I have a list with product links I open them one by one take the price and availability and go to next link.

Comment: THANK YOU :QHarr!!