# Excel automation fails second time code runs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am creating a VBA script to fetch some data from URLs from Excel cells, but the code gives error:

> "Run-time error '-2147023174' (800706ba)" error message or the "Run-time error '462' after the first run.

I have read - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs

However, I am too naive to understand the terms used there.

```
Private Sub loop_do_while()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Dim sTR As String
Dim pClass As String

Do While Cells(i, 4).Value <> ""
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate Cells(i, 4).Value
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set Doc = IE.document
    sTR = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(8).innerText)
    pClass = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("text-bold selected-version__price")(0).innerText)
    IE.Quit

    Cells(i, 5).Value = sTR
    Cells(i, 6).Value = pClass
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The way I am expecting it to function is, it takes URL from a column and put the fetched string in next column and repeat it on loop for subsequent rows.

Comment: Note: You open a new IE in each loop and close it. You could open a new IE *before* the loop, then just `IE.navigate` inside the loop and quit IE after the loop. So you can re-use the IE which should be faster. • In which line do you get the error?

Comment: See an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822698/how-to-remove-quotation-marks-after-web-scraping-with-vba/53823025#53823025)